# Where is wrong with the following "proof"?

Tags: real-analysis

> Where is wrong with the following "proof"?
>
> $f(x)$ Riemann-integrable $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)$ continuous almost everywhere 
>   $\Rightarrow$ $f(x)=g(x)$ almost everywhere, where $g$ is continuous $\Rightarrow$
>    $\int_a^x f(t)dt =  \int_a^x g(t)dt$ as Lebesgue integrals $\Rightarrow$  $\int_a^x f(t)dt =  \int_a^x g(t)dt$ as Riemann integrals  $\Rightarrow$ $F(x)=\int_a^x g(t)dt$.
>
> By the [Second Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SecondFundamentalTheoremofCalculus.html), $F'(x)=g(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

I don't see where the error is.

Comment: *What* is this supposed to prove?

Comment: The second implication is false. For example, a step function $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, but there's no continuous function $g$ satisfying $f=g$ a.e.

Answer (score 4):

The issue is with the second implication:

> $f(x)$ is continuous almost everywhere $\implies$ $f(x) = g(x)$ almost everywhere.

For example, consider any function with a jump discontinuity, for example the Heaviside function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 0 & x \le 0\\1 & x > 0\end{cases}.$$

Such an $f$ is Reimann integrable (on $[-1, 1]$, say), and continuous almost everywhere.  However, if $g(x) = f(x)$ a.e., then in particular,
$g(x) = 1$ for almost every $x \in (0, \delta)$ and $g(x) = 0$ for almost every $x$ in $(-\delta, 0)$.  Thus, $g$ cannot be continuous at $0$ (take $\epsilon = 1/2$).